# Pointer class member remains NULL after initialization by class method

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing

I am trying to implement a binary search tree data structure. I am having issues initializing my tree with the insert/insert_helper methods of the binary search tree class.

Using GDB, I can see that the root data member is not getting initialized on the first call to the `insert` method. I am having trouble figuring out why because I would expect, since I am passing pointers to the `insert_helper` method, I should be able to initialize that pointer within the method itself. Essentially, why when passing the `root` pointer in the first call to `insert_helper` can I not initialize the class `root` member properly? What rules does C++ have that does not allow this?

Any help or advice would be useful. Below are the relevant code snippets.

```
#ifndef BST_H_
#define BST_H_

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

template <typename T>
class Bin_Search_Tree {
private:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    struct Node {
    value_type data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node* parent;
    };
    Node* root;

    void free_tree(Node* rnode);
    size_type size_helper(const Node* rnode) const;
    Node* find_helper(const Node* rnode, const value_type& val) const;
    void print_tree_helper(const Node* rnode) const;
    bool insert_helper(Node* parent, Node* rnode, const value_type& val);
    bool remove_helper(Node* rnode, const value_type& val);
    Node* create_node(Node* parent, const value_type& val) const;
    Node* get_min(const Node* rnode) const;

public:
    Bin_Search_Tree() : root(nullptr) { }
    Bin_Search_Tree(const std::vector<value_type>& vals);
    ~Bin_Search_Tree() { free_tree(root); }

    bool empty() const { return (nullptr == root); }
    size_type size() const { return size_helper(root); }
    Node* find(const value_type& val) { return find_helper(root, val); }
    bool insert(const value_type& val) { insert_helper(nullptr, root, val); }
    bool remove(const value_type& val);
    void print_tree() const { print_tree_helper(root); }
};

template <typename T>
bool Bin_Search_Tree<T>::insert_helper(Node* parent, Node* rnode, const value_type& val) {
    if (nullptr == rnode) {
    rnode = create_node(parent, val);
    return true;
    } else if (val == rnode->data) {
    return false;
    } else if (rnode->data < val) {
    return insert_helper(rnode, rnode->right, val);
    } else {
    return insert_helper(rnode, rnode->left, val);
    }
}

template <typename T>
typename Bin_Search_Tree<T>::Node* Bin_Search_Tree<T>::create_node(Node* parent, const value_type& val) const {
    Node* inode = new Node;

    if (nullptr == inode) {
    throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    inode->data = val;
    inode->left = nullptr;
    inode->right = nullptr;
    inode->parent = parent;
    return inode;
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a pointer *to the thing you want to modify*, just like if it were an `int` or something else.

Comment: And initialisation happens before the body of the constructor. After that it's assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, the problem is I am passing by value rather than by reference. I since updated the class to work without the need for  pointer references but at least now I am aware of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function

```
template <typename T>
bool Bin_Search_Tree<T>::insert_helper(Node* parent, Node* rnode, const value_type& val) {
    if (nullptr == rnode) {
    rnode = create_node(parent, val);
    return true;
    } else if (val == rnode->data) {
    return false;
    } else if (rnode->data < val) {
    return insert_helper(rnode, rnode->right, val);
    } else {
    return insert_helper(rnode, rnode->left, val);
    }
}
```

Initially, `root=nullptr`, so the first `if` condition is satisfied. Then, you create a new node using

```
rnode = create_node(parent, val);
```

and return. However, `rnode` is local to the function as you are passing the root by value. When you return, the pointer is destroyed and you can no longer access the memory you allocated. Moreover, you never made any change as to where `root` points to, so it remains `nullptr`.

You can simply things by using the fact that this is a member function of the class - the `root` member is visible to the function. So, you do not need to pass it as an argument. It can be used directly inside the function, which should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are right, the problem is `rnode` is local to the function. As the molbdnilo in the comments above pointed out, I am passing the pointer by value. Up until today, I had never thought of passing a pointer by reference. I cannot use `root` directly in the function since the class itself is not recursively defined (i.e., it's just a fancy wrapper for the Node struct). I have restructured it to work without the need for pointer references though. Thanks again for the help.